# How do I add a line break at the mid point of a string split by whitespace

Tags: php, string, text

Using php: How can I insert a line break at the whitespace that falls in the relative middle of string? Or in other words, how do I count the words in a sentence and then put a line break in the sentence at the halfway point?

The idea is to avoid widows (abandoned words) on the second line of blog article titles by essentially cutting each title in half and putting it on two line if the title takes up more than one line.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
Hi All, I realized I needed the preg_split function to split the title by whitespaces. Sorry if that part was not clear in the question. I modified Asaph's answer and used this:

```
$title_length = strlen($title);
if($title_length > 30){
    $split = preg_split('/ /', $title, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $split_at = ceil(count($split) / 2);
    echo $split_at;
    $broken_title = '';
    $broken = false;
    foreach($split as $word_pos => $word){
        if($word_pos == $split_at  && $broken == false){
            $broken_title.= '<br />'."\n";
            $broken = true;
        }
        $broken_title .= $word." ";
    }
    $title = $broken_title;
}
```

I'm new to SO and I'm blown away by the power of the community. Cheers.

Comment: You want to add a line break in a sentence in the middle ?

Comment: Hi David, Yes. Any help clarifying is welcome. I actually need to check the length of a blog article title first. Then, if it is to big to fit on one line, I need to put a line break in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

Use PHP's [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function. You can use your string's length divided by 2 as the 2nd argument. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$sentence = 'This is a long sentence that I would like to break up into smaller pieces.';
$width = strlen($sentence)/2;
$wrapped = wordwrap($sentence, $width);
echo $wrapped;
?>
```

It outputs:

```
This is a long sentence that I would
like to break up into smaller pieces.
```

If you want HTML output, you can use the optional 3rd argument to specify the break characters. Like this:

```
$wrapped = wordwrap($sentence, $width, '<br />');
```

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Off to try it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Asaph This is bad because it can cut the sentence in the middle of a word.

Comment: @DavidBélanger No. It doesn't break in the middle of words. That's the point of the [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function.

Comment: @Asaph Yes the problem is if your string is encoded in UTF-8, wordwrap will cut in the UTF-8 entities, meaning that you will have something like that `Blabla�<br />gfdgdf` if you have accent or whatever require an entities.

Comment: @DavidBélanger Ok, [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) doesn't appear to have UTF-8 multibyte character support (yet!). Hopefully this isn't a problem for the OP. The question mentions nothing about UTF-8.

Comment: Your right on that Asaph, you could add `@iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);` to protect from this or check if it's UTF or not with `(preg_match('/[^\x00-\x7F]/S', $str) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

```
<?php
$Sentence = 'I will go to the school tomorrow if it is not raining outside and if David is ok with it.';
$Split = explode(' ', $Sentence);

$SplitAt = 0;
foreach($Split as $Word){
    $SplitAt+= strlen($Word)-1;
    if($SplitAt >= strlen($Sentence)){
        break;
    }
}

$NewSentence = wordwrap($Sentence, $SplitAt, '<br />' . PHP_EOL);


echo $NewSentence;
?>
```

Produce this :

> I will go to the school tomorrow if it is not<br />\n
>       raining outside and if David is ok with it.

**EDIT** : Added PHP_EOL to match all system plus html with <br />

Comment: Wow David, thank you. I'm not very familiar with regular expressions, but this seems really useful. Any reason I should use this approach rather than using the 'word_wrap()' function?

Comment: @BrandonBrown I am sorry I edited my post. It's better to go with word_wrap. I saw it was for a title somewhere, a title will have pretty much word with space.

Comment: @BrandonBrown Actually it's [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php), not `word_wrap()`. I updated my answer. Sorry about the typo initially.

Comment: FYI: `PHP_EOL` doesn't seem useful context because it will give you the server's native newline character, not the client's. Imagine you're running your LAMP site on linux and someone's browsing on Windows/IE. They get linux newlines in the markup. What's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Solution if you want to choose the number of the lines.

```
function splitSentence($sentence, $lines) {

    $words                  = explode(' ', $sentence);
    $max_line_length        = intval((strlen($sentence) / $lines));
    $current_line_length    = 0;
    $output                 = '';

    foreach ($words as $word) {
    
        $word_length = strlen($word) + 1; // 1 for removed whitespace

        if (($current_line_length + $word_length) <= $max_line_length) {
            $output .= $word.' ';
            $current_line_length += $word_length;
        }
        else {
            $output .= $word.'<br>';
            $current_line_length = 0;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```